# what is difference between regular Akka actor and Camel consumer actor?

Tags: akka, actor, consumer

A regular Akka actor is associated with a mailbox and dispather(thread pool), which can be set by configuration or programmatically. you can look up regular actor through path.
regular actor dequeue message form mailbox first and then processing the message, etc

Can i do the same to Camel consumer actor?
what is the differences between regular actor and camel consumer actor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do the same with a Camel Consumer Actor. The difference is that the [Consumer Actor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/camel.html#Consumer_Actors) registers itself to a Camel Endpoint.

Comment: thanks for your reply. so my understanding is that camel consumer will picks up a message from its end point, and put the message into the consumer's mailbox. this is all done by Camel component thread. Akka thread kicks in after the message is in the consumer's mailbox.  Am i right?

Comment: Yes, the Akka managed threads will run the Actor part, while the Camel managed threads will run the Camel Component code.